# How to download an audio message from a user in a telegram bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, bots, telegram

Expensive time of day. There is a question. I want to make a telegram bot that would be able to read voice messages from the user and download them to the server. The question is, how to make the bot automatically understand that audio was sent to it and save it to the specified directory?
P.S tried through

```
bot.on('voice', (msg)=>{
        bot.getFile(msg.voice.file_id, () => {
            bot.getFile(voiceId).then((resp) => {
                {
                    file_id = 'file_id',
                        file_size = 6666,
                    file_path = 'file_path'
                }
                bot.getFileLink(voiceId).then((resp) => {
                    'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/<file_path>'
                });
            });
        });
```

but the file is downloaded only the id and path of which I specified

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axios](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi3uey_vZbvAhXioXEKHf7GDn0QFjAAegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Faxios%2Faxios&usg=AOvVaw266wVW3XPRY46nOw2ULXdh) and `telegram.getFileLink()`: (This is a [telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org) example)

```
bot.on("voice",ctx => {
  ctx.telegram.getFileLink(ctx.message.vioce.file_id).then((url) => {
      axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" }).then((voice) => {
      fs.writefile(`./lib/voices/${ctx.from.id}/${ctx.message.vioce.file_id}.ogg`,voice)})
  })
})
```